# Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am getting below error .

```
Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object.
    at Object.exports.(anonymous function) [as isDocument] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/validate.js:86:15)
    at WriteBatch.set (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/write-batch.js:286:14)
    at DocumentReference.set (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/reference.js:420:8)
    at PainEntryService.createEntry (/user_code/services/entry-service.js:19:30)
    at /user_code/services/intentService.js:22:36
    at Function.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:146:23)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:22:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:18:12)
    at Function.handler (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:84:16)
```

I am using below code for creating the document

```
var docRef = this.dbManager.collection('tetst).doc(subjectId);
        var setAlan = docRef.set(EntryEntity.toJSON);
```

I have below code in the toJSON method

```
public toJSON(): testEntry {
        let returnJSON = {
            "entry_id": this.entry_id,
            "subject_id": this.subject_id,
            "entry_date": this.entry_date,
            "questionnaire": this.questionnaire,
            "entry_start_timestamp": this.entry_start_timestamp,
            "entry_end_timestamp": this.entry_end_timestamp,
            "entry_complete": this.entry_complete,
            //"responses": this.responses,
            "last_answered_question" : this.last_answered_question,
            "entry_status" : this.entry_status
        }

        return returnJSON;
    }
```

I am framing json object in the above method. If i print the json object, i am getting below content

{ entry_id: 'df2b4ad4-6a70-4304-a71f-3a63773ada61',
  subject_id: 'ABwppHHkzfY1Whp-lCHNnvEcuqvsbMKtZsg_ui9vc4jtpXSiAbh0fNsg6LxGkYq-Va3SOrwcvD-HAs7VQA',
  entry_date: '2018-06-15',
  questionnaire: 1,
  entry_start_timestamp: '2018-06-15T09:38:10.266Z',
  entry_end_timestamp: '2018-06-15T09:38:10.266Z',
  entry_complete: false,
  last_answered_question: 0,
  entry_status: 'active' }

How to solve above issue? is there any issue with json object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `toJSON` method. Currently you are passing a reference to a method to `set` when you need to pass the return value of the called method.

Change

```
var setAlan = docRef.set(EntryEntity.toJSON);
```

to

```
var setAlan = docRef.set(EntryEntity.toJSON());
```